# When do we still need the table and figure environments when we don't want the enclosed objects to float?

Tags: table-of-contents, floats, positioning, captions

The LaTeX Wikibook [writes](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables#Floating_with_table):

> Please understand: you do not *have to* use floating tables. It only
>   looks more professional. If you want to place your tables where they
>   lie in your source code, do not use `table` at all! This is a very
>   common misunderstanding among newcomers.

LaTeX works with an intricate [table placement algorithm](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39020/14996), but I often prefer immediate placement with the `H` placement specifier (enabled by the `float` package).

My understanding is that captions and table/figure numbering require the `table`/`figure` environments. Is this really so, or are there ways around that? What other reasons are there for using `table`/`figure` if we know that we don't want a particular object to float?

Comment: My opinion is that if something can't be allowed to float, then it doesn't need a caption. The purpose of the caption is to provide a description for something that can be far from the text referring to it; a graph or table that can't float has its description in the text around it.

Comment: @egreg (a) Maybe you have a bunch of tables in close succession showing trade statistics for 2 or 3 countries. Having the country name in a caption seems like a good idea. (b) It can be nice to have all table- or figure-like material be named and numbered, even if it doesn't float. One aspect of this is that this will provide an easy way to index the material (in a list of tables/figures/whateveryoudliketocallit or in the index of a book) and refer to it by number.

Comment: @egreg -- floats typically insert space around the floating object.  if a table happens to be the first (or perhaps only) thing in an appendix, this spacing and other features of the float interfere seriously with the positioning relative to the appendix header.  that does not always remove the need for a table caption.

Answer (score 3):

It is too long as a comment. [capt-of](http://ctan.org/pkg/capt-of) package documentation says as follows.

[image]